# Display a value from the model and refresh it on change

Tags: ariatemplates

I have a property in my model:

```
this.setData({myProp: "Hello World!"})
```

What I want is only display it in my template and refresh it when it changes.

The solution I currently have is to use a section, bind its refresh to the property and display the property in a macro. My issue is that I feel there should be another, simpler way to do it. It's IMHO too heavy (15ish lines), especially compared to angular's `{{myProp}}`

Does anyone have a simple and elegant implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I just had to use the [text widget](http://ariatemplates.com/usermanual/Text).

```
{@aria:Text {
    bind: {
        text : {
            to: "myProp",
            inside: data
        }
    }
}/}
```

It gives wierd results when inserted in the middle of a text, but a bit of CSS will solve it.

Comment: There is a display issue because Text widget, like all the other widgets has `.xWidget` CSS class which defines `vertical-align: middle` to have e.g. `@aria:Text` and the label of neighboring other text-based widgets vertically consistent. Unfortunately this creates a problem when you have normal text and `@aria:Text` in one line: [example](http://juliandescottes.github.io/instantat/#5189228fe4b05c9e5f8233cb). We'll have a look at it.